# How to fireRowClick in iccube 6

Tags: iccube, iccube-reporting

I'm trying to fire auto click on first row for a 'table' After Render. in icCube 6 (3961)

[image]

but when i use

```
function(context, data, $box) {
 context.fireRowClick(0)
}
```

i get error
context.fireRowClick is not a function

Comment: there is an issue with the context, we're going to fix this for the next release

Comment: thanks for fast reply

Answer (score 2):

This error has been repaired in >= icCube 6 (4036). Please update when it becomes available. As a workaround you could use the following fragment that sends event using the different context type:

```
function(context, data, $box) {
    if(context.fireRowClick){
        // context is table/widget context
        context.fireRowClick(0);    
    } else {
        // context is reporting context (before the fix)
        var axisIndex = data.getAxes().getAxisCount() - 1;        
        var event = new viz.event.SingleSelectionEvent({
            uniqueName : data.getAxes().getAxis(axisIndex).getMemberUniqueName(0,0),
            name : data.getAxes().getAxis(axisIndex).getMemberCaption(0,0),
        })
        context.eventMgr().fireEvent('rowClick', event)
    }
}
```

Comment: i put 'rowClick' event name on do Click event in the table preferences but it didn't work. if i put the 'rowClick' event in do Selection for example then it worked fine and selected the first row. the thing is that i also have on Row Click event in the same table that should pop up a different graph with the row header name from the first table...